# RestKit: given RKObjectMapping, object.class and JSON string, how to get mapped object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

Is there a way to use RestKit as an object mapper, say I give it a JSON string and an object mapping, then it gives me the object entity, without setting up the server and all those network related stuff?

Thanks!

updated:

what I need is:

1. give Restkit an RKObjectMapping, the object class and JSON string
2. get the parsed object.

what RestKit documentation told me is:

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://restkit.org"];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:articleMapping forKeyPath:@"articles"];
RKObjectLoader* loader = [RKObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/articles" delegate:self];
```

where I do not need to create the object manager and load objects.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the Wiki that has been provided?

[RestKit: Object mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)

I personally enjoy using AFNetworking for networking and parsing the JSON and then use MagicalRecord for object mapping and other Core Data work.

Comment: However I still could not understand what should I do in order to: 1. give Restkit an RKObjectMapping, the object class and JSON string 2. get the parsed object.

Comment: Try Mantle (see https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle and http://www.objc.at/mantle). It seems quite a bit more simple, and to the point if all you are looking for is object mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use:

```
RKObjectMappingOperation *op = [RKObjectMappingOperation mappingOperationFromObject:jsonDict toObject:myObject withMapping:[MyObject mapping]];
[op performMapping:&error];
```